# Original author of project that a company abandoned

Tags: copyright

I'm the original author of a project that was made on company time and resources. While waiting for this project to come to life it just died without any support on marketing it and not using it at all.

Now I'm wondering if I can use this as my own releasing it for proprietary purposes or as an open source project. Are there legal outcomes when in the case of the company taking it back as their own proprietary product?

I'm no longer an employee on said company.

Comment: Don't you have a clause in your work contract which says that any intellectual property you create while on the clock becomes the intellectual property of the company? That's pretty standard in the IT industry. At least where I am from.

Answer (score 3):

Using it without permission is copyright infringement and illegal.

Legally, you can try offering money to the company for the copyright or for a suitable license. For example offer them $1000 for a copy of the code licensed under the GPL license. If they accept, you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Consider a company car

If they aren’t using it; is it ok for you to take it without permission?

Same principle applies to IP.

Comment: It is more like taking the car home after you no longer work there.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I don't think whether you work there is relevant. Even if you work at the company, if they don't give you permission to take the car it's theft. Maybe you were assuming it's a company car that had been assigned to you?

Comment: Yes - the analogy only makes sense if it’s a company car.